# Centering stacked bars vertically in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to visualize sold items from timeseries. I'm using [Nick Rabinowitz's alluvial chart](http://nickrabinowitz.com/projects/d3/alluvial/alluvial.html) as a basis but have made few modifications to it. Everything else looks good but I would like to center the stacked bars vertically.

This is what my chart looks like at the moment:

[image]

```js
/*Original code obtained from http://nickrabinowitz.com/projects/d3/alluvial/alluvial.html*/

var data = {
  "times": [
    [{
      "id": "item1",
      "nodeName": "Item 1 50/2015",
      "nodeValue": 9,
      "incoming": []
    }, {
      "id": 1,
      "nodeName": "Item 2 50/2015",
      "nodeValue": 6,
      "incoming": []
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "nodeName": "Item 3 50/2015",
      "nodeValue": 3,
      "incoming": []
    }],
    [{
      "id": "item12",
      "nodeName": "Item 1 51/2015",
      "nodeValue": 8,
      "incoming": []
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "nodeName": "Item 2 51/2015",
      "nodeValue": 2,
      "incoming": []
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "nodeName": "Item 3 51/2015",
      "nodeValue": 5,
      "incoming": []
    }],
    [{
      "id": 6,
      "nodeName": "Item 1 52/2015",
      "nodeValue": 1,
      "incoming": []
    }, {
      "id": 7,
      "nodeName": "Item 2 52/2015",
      "nodeValue": 7,
      "incoming": []
    }, {
      "id": 8,
      "nodeName": "Item 3 50/2015",
      "nodeValue": 4,
      "incoming": []
    }]
  ],
  "links": [{
      "source": "item1",
      "target": "item12",
      "outValue": 9,
      "inValue": 8
    }, {
      "source": "item12",
      "target": 6,
      "outValue": 8,
      "inValue": 1
    }, {
      "source": 1,
      "target": 4,
      "outValue": 6,
      "inValue": 2
    }, {
      "source": 4,
      "target": 7,
      "outValue": 2,
      "inValue": 7
    }, {
      "source": 2,
      "target": 5,
      "outValue": 3,
      "inValue": 5
    }
    /*,
                {
                    "source": 5,
                    "target": 8,
                    "outValue": 5,
                    "inValue": 4
                }*/
  ]
};

/* Process Data */

// make a node lookup map
var nodeMap = (function() {
  var nm = {};
  data.times.forEach(function(nodes) {
    nodes.forEach(function(n) {
      nm[n.id] = n;
      // add links and assure node value
      n.links = [];
      n.incoming = [];
      n.nodeValue = n.nodeValue || 0;
    })
  });
  console.log(nm);
  return nm;
})();

// attach links to nodes
data.links.forEach(function(link) {
  console.log(link);
  nodeMap[link.source].links.push(link);
  nodeMap[link.target].incoming.push(link);
});

// sort by value and calculate offsets
data.times.forEach(function(nodes) {
  var nCumValue = 0;
  nodes.sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.descending(a.nodeValue, b.nodeValue)
  });
  nodes.forEach(function(n, i) {
    n.order = i;
    n.offsetValue = nCumValue;
    nCumValue += n.nodeValue;
    // same for links
    var lInCumValue;
    var lOutCumValue;
    // outgoing
    if (n.links) {
      lOutCumValue = 0;
      n.links.sort(function(a, b) {
        return d3.descending(a.outValue, b.outValue)
      });
      n.links.forEach(function(l) {
        l.outOffset = lOutCumValue;
        lOutCumValue += l.outValue;
      });
    }
    // incoming
    if (n.incoming) {
      lInCumValue = 0;
      n.incoming.sort(function(a, b) {
        return d3.descending(a.inValue, b.inValue)
      });
      n.incoming.forEach(function(l) {
        l.inOffset = lInCumValue;
        lInCumValue += l.inValue;
      });
    }
  })
});
data = data.times;

// calculate maxes
var maxn = d3.max(data, function(t) {
    return t.length
  }),
  maxv = d3.max(data, function(t) {
    return d3.sum(t, function(n) {
      return n.nodeValue
    })
  });

/* Make Vis */

// settings and scales
var w = 960,
  h = 500,
  gapratio = .5,
  padding = 7,
  x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(d3.range(data.length))
  .rangeBands([0, w], gapratio),
  y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, maxv])
  .range([0, h - padding * maxn]),
  area = d3.svg.area()
  .interpolate('monotone');

// root
var vis = d3.select("#alluvial")
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

// time slots
var times = vis.selectAll('g.time')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('svg:g')
  .attr('class', 'time')
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + x(i) + ",0)"
  });

// node bars
var nodes = times.selectAll('g.node')
  .data(function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .enter().append('svg:g')
  .attr('class', 'node');

nodes.append('svg:rect')
  .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
  .attr('y', function(n, i) {
    return y(n.offsetValue) + i * padding;
  })
  .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
  .attr('height', function(n) {
    return y(n.nodeValue)
  })
  .append('svg:title')
  .text(function(n) {
    return n.nodeName
  });

// links
var links = nodes.selectAll('path.link')
  .data(function(n) {
    return n.links || []
  })
  .enter().append('svg:path')
  .attr('class', 'link')
  .attr('d', function(l, i) {
    var source = nodeMap[l.source];
    var target = nodeMap[l.target];
    var gapWidth = x(0);
    var bandWidth = x.rangeBand() + gapWidth;

    var sourceybtm = y(source.offsetValue) +
      source.order * padding +
      y(l.outOffset) +
      y(l.outValue);
    var targetybtm = y(target.offsetValue) +
      target.order * padding +
      y(l.inOffset) +
      y(l.inValue);
    var sourceytop = y(source.offsetValue) +
      source.order * padding +
      y(l.outOffset);
    var targetytop = y(target.offsetValue) +
      target.order * padding +
      y(l.inOffset);

    var points = [
      [x.rangeBand(), sourceytop],
      [x.rangeBand() + gapWidth / 5, sourceytop],
      [bandWidth - gapWidth / 5, targetytop],
      [bandWidth, targetytop],
      [bandWidth, targetybtm],
      [bandWidth - gapWidth / 5, targetybtm],
      [x.rangeBand() + gapWidth / 5, sourceybtm],
      [x.rangeBand(), sourceybtm]
    ];

    return area(points);
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 3em;
}
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
.link {
  fill: #000;
  stroke: none;
  opacity: .3;
}
.node {
  stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="alluvial"></div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dztkv2pa/) if you like to play around with the code.

The solution probably lies somewhere in counting the full height of the bar and calculating the node offsets from the centerpoint.

The way the original code is structured looks like to be calculating offsets per node and then using these offsets to calculate node positions. I probably need to be able to modify this calculated offset in someway at somepoint but I just can't figure out how and where. If it is even possible.

If that isn't possible, is there another way in d3 to achieve visually similar results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try calculated the maximum full height using (I've just added the lines that change, the rest is the same):

```
//calculate the max full height
var maxHeight=0;
data.times.forEach(function(nodes,p) {
    var curHeight=0;
    nodes.forEach(function(n) {
    curHeight+=n.nodeValue;
    });
  if(curHeight > maxHeight) maxHeight=curHeight
});
```

And then adding `(maxHeight/2 - curHeight/2)` to the offset, `curHeight` being the total height of the nodes for each band.

To do this you can add a couple lines to the loop calculating the offset:

```
// sort by value and calculate offsets
data.times.forEach(function(nodes,p) {
  var nCumValue = 0;
  nodes.sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.descending(a.nodeValue, b.nodeValue)
  });  

  var bandHeight = 0;
  nodes.forEach(function(n) {
    bandHeight+=n.nodeValue;
  });

  nodes.forEach(function(n, i) {
    n.order = i;
    n.offsetValue = nCumValue + (maxHeight/2-bandHeight/2);
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5oc89k3n/) with these changes.

Comment: Well, that was a simple solution. And it worked. Thank you!